# identical() but for environments/R6 in base R?

Tags: r

If I can run code before and after a user runs some code, how can I detect which variables were set or changed using base R? I can do this using `identical()` for non-environment objects. But is there a base-R solution for environments, including R6 classes?

Here's a solution using `identical()` which fails for envs/R6:

```r
# Copy of initial vars
this_frame = sys.frame()
start_vars = ls()
start_copy = lapply(start_vars, get, envir = this_frame )
names(start_copy) = start_vars

# (user code here)

# Assess what's new and what's changed
end_vars = ls()
new_vars = end_vars[end_vars %in% start_vars == FALSE]
old_vars = end_vars[end_vars %in% start_vars == TRUE]
changed_vars = old_vars[sapply(old_vars, function(x) identical(get(x, envir = this_frame), start_copy[[x]])) == FALSE]
```

I'm writing a package that lets users run code in a separate session. I'd like to return only objects that were changed.

Answer (score 1):

This solution detects changes in an environment, sub-environments, and R6-classes.

## General approach

1. run `start_state = env_as_list()` on `sys.frame()`which stores everything in a list and recursively converts all environments/R6 and sub-environments/R6 to `list`.
2. Let the user manipulate stuff
3. Run `end_state = env_as_list()` and use `identical()` to detect changes between `start_state` and `end_state`.

```r
env_as_list = function(env) {
  rapply(
    object = as.list(env, all.names = TRUE), 
    f = function(x) {
      if ("R6" %in% class(x)) {
        # R6 to list without recursion
        x = as.list(x, all.names = TRUE)
        x$.__enclos_env__$self = NULL
        x$.__enclos_env__$super = NULL
        env_as_list(x)
      } else if (is.environment(x)) {
        env_as_list(x)
      } else {
        stop("Impossible to get here")
      }
    },
    classes = c("environment", "R6"),
    how = "replace"
  )
}
```

## Demonstration

Let's test it: let's fill `globalenv()` with a some stuff to begin with:

```r
R6_class = R6::R6Class("Testing", list(a = 1))
my_R6 = R6_class$new()

my_env = new.env()
my_env$sub_env = new.env()
my_env$sub_env$some_value = 2

my_regular = rnorm(5)
```

Snapshot time!

```r
start_state = env_as_list(sys.frame())
```

Let the user play:

```r
my_R6$a = 99  # Change R6
new_regular = 3  # new var
my_env$sub_env$some_value = 99  # Change sub-environment
```

Snapshot again!

```r
end_state = env_as_list(sys.frame())
end_state$start_state = NULL  # don't include this
```

Did nothing change?

```
> identical(start_state, end_state))
# FALSE
```

Which variables changed?

```
> is_same = lapply(names(end_state), function(x) identical(start_state[[x]], end_state[[x]]))
> names(end_state)[is_same == FALSE]
# "my_env"      "new_regular"     "my_R6"
```

## Bonus

You can also use this to compute the size of an environment, including all R6 and sub-environments. Simply:

```r
object.size(env_as_list(globalenv()))
```